# How to Use apiHttpClient in Google PHP API Client

Tags: google-api-client

I have been beating my head around this one; the examples provided in the [PHP client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) under "**apps**" shows how to use the apiHttpRequest class to make HTTP request to the Provisioning API. The example shows how to list and delete a user in a domain (that is apps enabled) but I am having a had time understanding how to POST to the provision API (feeds) because I will like to programatically create groups using the apiHttpRequest. Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

I have include a code sample for deleting a user

```
// Deleting a User Alias from a Domain (Experimental)
  $domain = "example.com";
  $user = rawurlencode("user@domain.com");
  $req = new apiHttpRequest("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/$domain/$user", 'DELETE');
  $resp = $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
  print "<h1>Deleting a User Alias from a Domain</h1>: <pre>" . $resp->getResponseBody() . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I see, one has to create an **Atom XML** mockup and pass it as a string. Is there a more elegant way of handling this? We are not using Zend and so we have to create this ourselves.